# PHP creates new instance when pushing element

Tags: php, arrays, reference

Why does PHP create a new array when I push an element?

```
$a = array();
$b = $a;

$b[] = "Hello!";
echo count($a);
echo count($b);
```

Here you would expect the count for $a and $b to be equal, but they are not.

Comment: They are not equal since $a is empty and $b have 1 value.

Comment: what is unexpected here exactly? I don't see anything wrong

Comment: In the vast majority of popular programming languages, assignments of an array-like object would be by reference.

Comment: which language doing that??

Comment: @Akam well, javascript) However, `Array` in javascript is an `Object`, but in php it is not.

Comment: Well.. Java, Python, C#, javascript, VB, C++, C is the one i know of which does it by reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, PHP is copying values when assigning them. If you want a reference, you can use the [`&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

```
$a = array();
$b = &$a;

$b[] = "Hello!";
echo count($a);  // prints 1
echo count($b);  // prints 1
```

Comment: @CORRUPT agreed, that's why I added the quotes. I'll update my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$a` and `$b` are two separate variables, when you assign `$b = $a` you are only copying the contents of `$a` to `$b`, not making them both point to the same array.

To do this, you need to pass by references instead:

```
$b = &$a;
```

In this case, $b points to the reference to $a, which means they both point to the same array, any change to one will change on both.